# I need to check a checkbox on tab in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a windows form where in I had a textbox and checkbox, I need to check checkbox on tabbing from textbox to checkbox. I tried using get focus but not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = True
    End If

End Sub
```